# vb.net print datagridview column alignment

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, alignment

My grid displays with the first 3 columns left aligned and the next 4 right aligned.

Using this code `e.Graphics.DrawString(Stock.gdColours(j, i).Value, f, Brushes.Black, x, y + 4)`

all columns print left aligned. 
Because I need columns 3 onward to be right aligned I added:

```
If j >2 Then 
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far 
Else 
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near

e.Graphics.DrawString(Stock.gdColours(j, i).Value, f, Brushes.Black, x, y + 4, sf)
```

But the result is that the alignment is correct but Colums 3 onward have all appeared from Column 2 onward.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have formatted your code, it is right? It seems that an `EnfIF` is missing...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown check your comment its end if not enfif

Comment: @SATSON sorry for that, It's been some years I don't touch vb. Anyway, you understand...

Comment: There is an 'end if' before the e.graphics - I just missed copying it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me is below. I was using X1, X2 and X3 as the column positions for near aligned strings. When I changed the middle column to be far aligned, I set the X position of the middle column to be just to the left of the third column.

```
         For intRow As Integer = 0 To _aryTopTable.GetLength(0) - 1
            'Draw each row element
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_aryTopTable(intRow, 0), _tableFont, Brushes.Black, X1, Y, format)
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_aryTopTable(intRow, 1), _tableFont, Brushes.Black, X3 - 10, Y, format)
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_aryTopTable(intRow, 2), _tableFont, Brushes.Black, X3, Y, format)
            'Advance Y
            Y = Y + _tableFont.Height + Yp
        Next
```

Comment: There is no need for the code to be so much "tabbed".